# It is possible to hide part of labels google chart

Tags: google-visualization, label

1. I want to hide couple labels, first 2 and last 2 in axis X.
2. I want to disable black line at the bottom of the graph.

I'm able to do it after the chart is loaded - using javascript and change it dynamically. When I add new data and use draw method, Graph is overwriting my dynamic stylesheets changes. I was trying to set it as an option in graph initializer but I couldn't find the solution for that.

I use areaChart.

It was 3 years ago. I don't need it anymore. I'm leaving this question for others.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard understanding what you're trying to do, but I think I get it.

As I read it, you want to eliminate two variables from your `DataTable` when you plot your chart (to prevent them from being in the legend)? Assuming that's the case, you can either take them out of the data table, or use a `ChartWrapper` on your object, and set the `view:{columns:[x,y,z]}` option to the ChartWrapper. Assuming you can't change the `DataTable`, or a `ChartWrapper` isn't an option, and you just want to not have certain plotted objects appear in your chart but not in the legend, you want to set the `series` option. For example, assuming three columns in your `DataTable`, you can hide the third item as:

```
series: [{visibleInLegend:true}, {visibleInLegend:true}, {visibleInLegend:false}],
```

Second of all, if you want to hide the horizontal axis, you need to have continuous data, and set `hAxis.baselineColor` to `'clear'`.

Comment: No, he's talking about the axis labels. For instance, you might have a vertical axis which runs from 0 to 10, with a total of 11 ticks (including the one at the top and the one at the bottom) but the Y-values of the data are all greater than 1.0 and less than 9.0, so you want to leave omit the "0" label at the bottom and the "10" label at the top.

Answer (score 0):

To hide some of the tick-mark labels, use `ticks:` *ticklist* to label the axis, and for some of the labels in ticklist use an `{v:`*value*`,f:`*label*`}` structure definition, with a zero-length string for the label.

Here's an example. Note the omitted labels for some of the ticks on each vertical axis. View source to see how I did it:

http://www.sealevel.info/co2_and_ch4c.html

Note the tick list definitions. This one is for the left vertical axis:

```js
var vticklist1 = [{v:235,f:''},{v:250,f:''},275,300,325,350,375,400,{v:425,f:'ppmv'}];
```

The first & second ticks (at the bottom, for values 235 and 250) display no labels. The next six ticks, for values 275-400, display normally. The last (top) tick displays as "ppmv" instead of 425.  The result looks like this:

[image: vertical axis with some tick labels hidden]